# send value from anchor to popup

Tags: php, jquery, anchor

I am using this way to show a popup div

`<a href="<?php echo is_user_logged_in() ? '#ask-question-div' : '#login' ?>" class="open-question-popup">Ask Question</a>`

when clicking on the anchor of class 'open-question-popup', several anchors share the same popup, so they all have the same anchor code, the problem is I want to send the title of each of the parent div to the popup (#ask-question-div) to be shown as a header when the corresponding anchor element is clicked.

Comment: you mean target="_blank" attribute in <a> tag?

Comment: yes the <a> tag but target is a popup div in the same page

Answer (score 0):

Without relevant html shown here is a generic approach

```
$('.open-question-popup').on('clcik', function(){
  // `this` is the `<a>` event occurred on 
  var title = $(this).closest('div').attr('title');// not clear where value should come from
  $('#ask-question-div').find(someElement).text(title);//not clear where to put it

})
```

Comment: this doesnt work, i guess the document is not catching the click event of <a> element

Comment: Could be the elements are added after code runs in which case you need to delegate the event listener. please provide a [mcve]